# Define array members to be always non-negative in C language before the solving process

Tags: arrays, c, math, types, least-squares

I am solving an overdetermined sparse linear problem using a C code. The code is using the LSQR method to find the solutions. There are 6 unknowns for every equation. One of the solutions is a one-dimensional array with the type of `double`, which I don’t want to be negative during the solving process. Is there any way to do that?
For example, is there any way to define the array to be always positive or zero before the process?

Comment: No, there is no way. You will have to add checking in some point.

Comment: I agree with Eugene — with the `double` type, there is no way to mandate non-negative values in the type.  You will have to manage it in code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. what about float type?

Comment: `float` is no different from `double` from this perspective. It is a signed type

Comment: Same comment for `float`, and also `long double`.  The floating-point types in standard C are all inherently signed types, storing both negative and positive values.

Comment: Note that even if you were able to find a hypothetical unsigned type for your application, I doubt that it would help you to do what you are asking for. The C type-checking won't restrict assigning negative values to unsigned types in the run-time.